# Use of the definite article: "restricts flow" or "restricts the flow"

Tags: definite-articles

We are writing technical documentation and a sentence looks more or less like this:

> 1. "The inside diameter of the pipe is reduced and thus restricts flow of water."
> 2. "The inside diameter of the pipe is reduced and thus restricts the flow of water."
> 3. "The inside diameter of the pipe is reduced and thus restricts the flow of the water."

Which is correct/false or better/worse?

Comment: A less wordy version, which may or may not please your ear, is:  The pipe's inside diameter is reduced and restricts water flow.

Comment: I might add:  My version has only 10 words; your suggested versions have 14, 15, and 16, respectively.  I prefer economy of expression as long as it does not interfere with my reader's understanding.

Answer (score 2):

Although this is somewhat a matter of opinion (i.e., one can choose between S2 and S3, but S1 is out of the question for me), I will say that S#2 is the better choice. All three sentences are understandable, but S1 is ungrammatical, in my opinion, because the definite article is required for the phrase *the flow of water*. At best, S1 is exceedingly poor style: not everyone agrees on what is and is not grammatical, but "*I know it when I see it*".